# How to increase acrofield(textfield) size to fit text in itext?

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a pdf template having a multi line textfield.While filling up the textfield at run-time using itext, I want to increase the textfield size so that the entire content is visible.
I know similar questions have been posted previously.e.g. the following link suggests a solution but I am too new to itext to make it work.

[How to display floating textfield depending on the text content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270556/how-to-display-floating-textfield-depending-on-the-text-content)

I know setting font size 0 automatically adjust the font size to fit in the text, but that is not an option for me since I can't reduce the font size.

So kindly provide me an workable example if possible.

Comment: In which direction shall the field increase? Is there enough free space in that direction?

Comment: It should increase vertically.And yes, there is some space which can be occupied.

Comment: In that case, why not once manually extending the text field of the template vertically as far as possible to start with?

Comment: Problem is. it wont look good if the incoming text is small. e.g. if it is one line text, displaying it in a huge box wont look good.On the other hand there can be a possibility that the text is larger than the text field also.So deciding the text field size dynamically is the best available option it seems.

Comment: This should give you a hint how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072468/fit-text-in-textfield-itext